# Concurrent HTTP requests in a background job (sidekiq)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob, typhoeus

I want to check 50k RSS feeds for updates.  Right now it takes a *-looong-* time, so I began looking into gems that do parallel HTTP requests like **[typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus)**, though sidekiq and typhoeus  [don't play well together](https://twitter.com/mperham/status/477479180725022720).

What's a good way to do a bunch of simultaneous HTTP requests in the background?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/httprb/http claims to be pretty fast but I have not tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) - it runs on top of eventmachine which is library for non-blocking IO.